# Find $\ker(T)$ and determine whether the linear tranformation $T$ is one-to-one

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm lost on how to find $\ker(T)$ and determine whether a linear transformation is one-to-one. I'm supposed to find $T:R^2 \to R^2$ where $T(x,y) = (y, x)$.

I can't find any example that makes sense to me on how to find the kernel of a transformation. Also, I understand how a function is one-to-one, but I'm having a really hard time transitioning to thinking of a function as a linear transformation and how I'd determine if the linear transformation is one-to-one. I'd show the work I've done so far, but I can't make it past the first step -_-

Sorry if I come off as vague in anyway, but I really am completely lost!

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!
-Frank

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the kernel is the set of vectors in the domain which are sent to the zero vector by $T.$ In other words, you're looking for all the pairs $(x,y) \in R^2$ such that $T(x,y) = (0,0).$ But $T(x,y) = (y,x),$ and by definition this equals $(0,0)$ exactly when $y = 0$ and $x = 0$ (i.e. the coordinates must coincide). Hence the only vector which is sent to $0$ by $T$ is $(x,y) = (0,0)$.

Now there is a basic but very important result of linear algebra which states that a linear mapping $T$ is injective exactly when its kernel is trivial, i.e., consists only of the zero vector. Hence, by that result, we know that $T$ is injective without even having to check directly.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $T(\mathbf{x_1}) = T(\mathbf{x_2})$, with $\mathbf{x_1} = (x_1,y_1)$, and $\mathbf{x_2} = (x_2,y_2)$, then:

$(y_1,x_1) = (y_2,x_2)$.

Thus: $x_1 = x_2$, and $y_1 = y_2$.

Thus: $\mathbf{x_1} = \mathbf{x_2}$.

Thus: $T$ is one-to-one.

This implies $Ker(T) = \{(0,0)\}$

**Note:** You are not alone for being lost. You came to the right place. Welcome aboard !

Comment: You can post it and share your solutions with the community.

Comment: Doing so now, sorry for the large comment

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response! Just to make sure I understand, we can make the assumption T(x1) = T(x2) because **x2** is in the other space, so it would follow that y2 is also associated with y1 (because they're both in vector spaces that we can assume meet the criteria to be vector spaces)? Then, no matter what x1 and y1 are at any given point they can be mapped to the **0** because of the rule T(**0** * X1) = **0**? Thanks again, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @FrankA.: yes, that is how you prove that T is 1-1.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to finding the kernel is a more direct solution.

Recall that the definition of $\ker(T)$ for some $T$ is as follows:
$$
\ker(T) \equiv \{ x \in D(T) \mid T(x) = 0\}
$$
where $D(T)$ stands for the domain of $T$.

Now set $T : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 \; (x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$ then we need to find
$$
\ker(T) \equiv \{ (x,y) \mid (y,x) = (0,0) \}
$$
Now the property $(y,x) = (0,0)$ is only true when both $x = 0, y=0$ thus the only element is $(0,0)$ so that
$$
\ker(T) = \{ (0,0) \}
$$

Now to prove that $T$ is injective I would normally do so directly by the definition. An alternative proof is by seeing that $T^{-1}(x,y) = (y,x)$ is well defined and $T^{-1} \circ T = e$ where $e$ stands for the identity map ($x \mapsto x$).

The existence of the well defined right-inverse implies that the function is injective proof can be found [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Injection_iff_Left_Inverse).

EDIT: Going to explain injectivity a little

In general a mapping $T$ of some-sort is injective if, given $x,y \in D(T)$ such that
$$
T(x) = T(y)
$$
we have that $x=y$. In laymans terms, if the function applied at two points has the same value, then it actually implies that the two points are the same point. Again above $D(T)$ stands for the domain of $T$.

Now a transformation, like what you have is simply a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ so now in order to show that $T$ is injective, we need to show that whenever
$$
T(x_1,y_1) = T(x_2,y_2)
$$
we actually have that $(x_1,y_1) = (x_2,y_2)$. Well, let $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ whereas $T(x_1,y_1) = T(x_2,y_2)$. By the definition of $T$ you have this is equivalent to saying that
$$
(y_1,x_1) = (y_2,x_2)
$$
but really this means that $y_1 = y_2, x_1 = x_2$ which in turn implies that $(x_1,y_1) = (x_2,y_2)$ so, thus, we have shown that $T$ is indeed injective.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding! Just to make sure that I understand the definition correctly, ker(T) can only be the kernel of T if and only if x is in the domain of T and the Transformation is = 0? Then the (x,y) you plug in must produce (0,0) from (y,x) in order to be the kernel? Also, I don't think I've heard of proving that T is injective. My last class my professor blasted through like the last three sections of the book because we were behind and we had to finish everything before our last test, so I think I missed some of the important stuff trying to keep up. Thanks again!

Comment: @FrankA. Indeed you are correct on the definition of the kernel. I'll revise my post with the definition of injective and an explanation of a direct proof of injectivity.